Framework platypus
I heard frameworks are executable files, but need to be linked like object files... and have header files associated with them...
Sounds like some kind of platypus file to me.
Questions:
1: Do I need to use a specific language and compiling tools to use framework functions in my program?
2: If I don't want to write a program, can I run the framework directly from the terminal as an executable? A hole's a hole, if it's an executable I should be able to run it like one.
Tried it before, didn't work out too well, xcode couldn't see it

Frameworks are not executable files.  They are libraries of code that make drawing windows and GUIs easier.  Many of them contain source code that allows your to code to have the same GUI on multiple platforms.

The languages supported by the GUI framework depend on the GUI framework.  For example, wxWidgets and Qt both support C++ and Python.  You'll have to search the specific framework for more details.

There are applications that allow you to design a GUI and it will create an executable for you.  Software recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

I'm trying to use a private framework that Apple really doesn't want people touching. Does that change anything? Btw, I don't plan on having my program in the app store, so they can go to hell if they don't like it, I'm doing it anyway.

If you don't want to write code nor understand what a framework is, you are probably on the wrong site, the wrong project and using the wrong tools... Please remove the tags [c++], [xcode] and [compilation] from your question. Thanks anyway for asking.
